# Google Drive API get document contents without comments

Tags: google-drive-api

So I've successfully managed to grab the `text/html` content of a document on Google Drive but I'm wondering if there's a way I can get the contents without the comments. I've had a skim through the docs and I can only see a way of listing the comments rather than removing them.

Here's an example of the HTML returned from Google Docs (from within the `body` tag):

```
<p class="c4">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper commodo orci, id pretium magna luctus sed. Sed</span>
  <sup><a href="#cmnt1" name="cmnt_ref1">[a]</a></sup>
  <span>&nbsp;elementum consequat erat in bibendum. Donec lobortis convallis urna, ac sodales quam cursus vel. Mauris nec augue eu ligula ultricies blandit. Aenean blandit bibendum volutpat. In gravida turpis sed turpis adipiscing tempus. Nullam ut nunc sed nunc adipiscing ve</span>
  <span>hicula ac vel tellus. Donec elit lacus, auctor a sodales viverra, viverra sed felis. Mauris ornare velit ac lacus placera</span>
  <sup><a href="#cmnt2" name="cmnt_ref2">[b]</a></sup>
  <span>t, sit amet tincidunt eros pellentesque. Nullam neque massa, sagittis ac lacinia eleifend, placerat at elit. Fusce ultrices vulputate congue. Nulla pellentesque elit vitae elit faucibus, sit amet dapibus nunc eleifend. Duis placerat sapien at nulla congue, quis commodo nisi tempor. Duis auctor nunc ut augue pretium suscipit.</span>
</p>
<p class="c1">
  <span></span>
</p>
<p class="c4">
  <span>Sed nec bibendum turpis, id pharetra est. Mauris et pretium nisi. Nullam non imperdiet sapien. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris rhoncus magna magna, vitae rutrum enim scelerisque ac. Aenean consequat euismod nibh, sed dignissim velit consequat vitae. Fusce vel placerat turpis. Sed ut dignissim risus. Etiam </span>
  <span>luctus tincidunt nunc id volutpat. Ut ac pharetra quam, nec imperdiet mauris. Fusce consectetur vitae est eget laoreet. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Praesent sit am</span>
  <sup><a href="#cmnt3" name="cmnt_ref3">[c]</a></sup>
  <span>et arcu facilisis odio cursus pharetra ac vulputate lorem. Nullam pharetra viverra quam, a placerat purus convallis sollicitudin. Donec bibendum est ac libero sodales tempus vel vel lectus. Sed commodo bibendum sapien nec tincidunt.</span>
</p>
<p class="c1">
  <span></span>
</p>
<div class="c3">
  <p class="c0">
    <a href="#cmnt_ref1" name="cmnt1">[a]</a>
    <span>Ahmed Nuaman:</span>
  </p>
  <p class="c0">
    <span>Here's a comment</span>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="c3">
  <p class="c0">
    <a href="#cmnt_ref2" name="cmnt2">[b]</a>
    <span>Ahmed Nuaman:</span>
  </p>
  <p class="c0">
    <span>Here's another comment</span>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="c3">
  <p class="c0">
    <a href="#cmnt_ref3" name="cmnt3">[c]</a>
    <span>Ahmed Nuaman:</span>
  </p>
  <p class="c0">
    <span>Another further comment</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Which URL are you using to fetch the HTML contents? I suspect that instead of using exportLinks:text/html, you're using one of the convenience URLs.

Comment: So I'm using `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files` to fetch a folder, then looking for docs with mime type of `application/vnd.google-apps.document`, then using the export links `text/html` URL, downloading that and grabbing the HTML.

Comment: That sounds correct. So the result of text/html exportLink is including comments embedded within the HTML? Could you paste the file resource and the exported HTML here.

Comment: That's correct. I can't paste in the content as it's confidential.

Comment: Create a non confidential document and paste that

Comment: All done. This is just a sample but notice how `<sup>` tags are added for cites to the comments.